# How to make Tkinter button open in the same windows like in many other programs

Tags: python-3.x, button, tkinter

I have a program calculator, the button code opens a new window, but I want the button calculator run in the same window but not two separate, how do I instead run my code in the same windows?
P.S. the code is not mine, it is as an example

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Math Lab")
root.geometry("1400x1000")
heading = Label(root, text = "Welcome to the MATH Lab", font=("Berlin Sans FB", 40, "bold"), fg= "steelblue").pack()
root.configure(background= "powder blue")


def calculator():
    w = Tk()
    w.geometry("1400x1000")

    def evaluate1():
        res.configure(text="Answer: " + str(eval(entry.get())))

    def evaluate(event):
        res.configure(text="Answer: " + str(eval(entry.get())))

    but1 = Button(w, text="Enter", width=10, height=3)
    but1.place(x=650, y=100)
    but1.config(command=evaluate1)

    Label(w, text="Your Expression:").pack()
    entry = Entry(w)
    entry.bind("<Return>", evaluate)
    entry.pack()
    res = Label(w)
    res.pack()
    w.mainloop()

but1=Button(root,text="Calculator",width = 10, height = 3)
but1.place(x=100, y=100)
but1.config(command = calculator)


root.mainloop()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why would you post code that isn't yours? Show us _your_ code.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are requesting a new window:

```
    w = Tk()
```

Replace it with

```
    w = root
```

and you are good to go.
(Well, you'll want to tidy up some x,y offsets, for aesthetics.)